# Logstash unable to start pipeline

Tags: java, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I am working with Logstash v7.15.1 and when I am trying to run it, I am getting below error which I am unable to figure out. Will someone help me to fix this?

Note - I have removed several plugins comes bundled with Logstash as all were not part of my requirement.

```
[2021-11-10T11:38:45.045Z][ERROR][logstash.agent ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:logstash, :exception=>"Java::JavaLang::NoSuchMethodError", :message=>"java.nio.MappedByteBuffer.position(I)Ljava/nio/MappedByteBuffer;", :backtrace=>["org.logstash.ackedqueue.io.MmapPageIOV2.create(MmapPageIOV2.java:194)", "org.logstash.ackedqueue.Queue.newCheckpointedHeadpage(Queue.java:352)", "org.logstash.ackedqueue.Queue.openPages(Queue.java:209)", "org.logstash.ackedqueue.Queue.open(Queue.java:176)", "org.logstash.ackedqueue.ext.JRubyAckedQueueExt.open(JRubyAckedQueueExt.java:123)", "org.logstash.ackedqueue.ext.JRubyWrappedAckedQueueExt.initialize(JRubyWrappedAckedQueueExt.java:65)", "org.logstash.ackedqueue.QueueFactoryExt.create(QueueFactoryExt.java:62)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt.openQueue(AbstractPipelineExt.java:205)", "org.logstash.execution.AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$openQueue.call(AbstractPipelineExt$INVOKER$i$0$0$openQueue.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:355)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:144)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.InterpreterEngine.processCall(InterpreterEngine.java:345)", "org.jruby.ir.interpreter.StartupInterpreterEngine.interpret(StartupInterpreterEngine.java:72)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.INTERPRET_METHOD(MixedModeIRMethod.java:86)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:73)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:85)", "org.jruby.RubyClass.newInstance(RubyClass.java:939)", "org.jruby.RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.call(RubyClass$INVOKER$i$newInstance.gen)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "opt.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52)", "opt.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.pipeline_action.create.RUBY$method$execute$0$__VARARGS__(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledIRMethod.call(CompiledIRMethod.java:80)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.MixedModeIRMethod.call(MixedModeIRMethod.java:70)", "org.jruby.ir.targets.InvokeSite.invoke(InvokeSite.java:207)", "opt.logstash.logstash_minus_core.lib.logstash.agent.RUBY$block$converge_state$2(/opt/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:391)", "org.jruby.runtime.CompiledIRBlockBody.callDirect(CompiledIRBlockBody.java:138)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:58)", "org.jruby.runtime.IRBlockBody.call(IRBlockBody.java:52)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:139)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:318)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:105)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"]}
warning: thread "Converge PipelineAction::Create<logstash>" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
LogStash::Error: Don't know how to handle `Java::JavaLang::NoSuchMethodError` for `PipelineAction::Create<logstash>`
create at org/logstash/execution/ConvergeResultExt.java:135
```

Comment: What exactly did you run to get this output?

Comment: How are you trying to run logstash? What is your pipeline configuration? Also, what plugins did you remove? I would not recommend remove any bundled plugins. Do you have anything else in the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for posting incomplete information. After hours of troubleshooting, I was able to fix the issue. It was related to using different version of ruby and java. FYI, I am running Logstash in container and then deploying it on K8s cluster. I have removed plugins from Logstash source code itself and then build it.